# Wildly inconsistent and incorrect lighting in opengl

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, pyopengl, lighting

I followed a tutorial to add simple diffuse lighting, but the lighting is very much broken:

[image: Sample object]

On top of being inconsistent, all the diffuse component completely disappears at some camera angles (camera position seems to have no effect on this)

The vertex shader:

```c
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 vNormal;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 fNormal;
layout (location = 3) out vec4 fPos;

uniform mat4 MVMatrix;
uniform mat4 PMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = PMatrix * (MVMatrix * vPosition);
    fNormal = normalize(inverse(transpose(MVMatrix))*vNormal);
    fPos = MVMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 fNormal;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 fPos;
uniform vec4 objColour;

void main()
{
    vec3 lightColour = vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.8);
    vec3 lightPos = vec3(10, 20, 30);
    float ambientStrength = 0.4;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColour;

    vec3 diffLightDir = normalize(lightPos - vec3(fPos));
    float diff = max(dot(vec3(fNormal), diffLightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColour;
    
    vec3 rgb = (ambient + diffuse) * objColour.rgb;
    fColor = vec4(rgb, objColour.a);
}
```

Normal calculation (Due to the pythonnic nature, I did not follow a tutorial and this is probably the issue)

```py
self.vertices = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
self.normals = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
data = Wavefront(r"C:\Users\cwinm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\holder.obj", collect_faces=True)
all_vertices = data.vertices
for mesh in data.mesh_list:
    for face in mesh.faces:
        face_vertices = np.array([all_vertices[face[i]] for i in range(3)])
        
        normal = np.cross(face_vertices[0]-face_vertices[1], face_vertices[2] - face_vertices[1])
        normal /= np.linalg.norm(normal)

        self.vertices = np.append(self.vertices, face_vertices)
        for i in range(3): self.normals = np.append(self.normals, normal)
self.index = index_getter(len(self.vertices))
self.vertices.resize((len(self.vertices)//3, 3))
self.vertices = np.array(self.vertices * [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], dtype=np.float32)
```

(The local vertices and normals are then appended to a global vertex and normal buffer, which is pushed to OpenGL after initialisation)

VBO creation (also probably a problem)

```py
vPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "vPosition")
vNormalLoc = glGetAttribLocation(self.program, "vNormal")

self.Buffers[self.PositionBuffer] = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.Buffers[self.PositionBuffer])
glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices.nbytes, self.vertices, 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc)

self.Buffers[self.NormalBuffer] = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.Buffers[self.NormalBuffer])
glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.normals.nbytes, self.normals, 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(vNormalLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vNormalLoc)
```

Ambient lighting, the matrices, and the vertex processing is all functional, things only broke when I added normals and (attempted) diffuse lighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is that normal here has type `np.float64`.

```
normal = np.cross(face_vertices[0]-face_vertices[1], face_vertices[2] - face_vertices[1])
normal /= np.linalg.norm(normal)
```

And `self.normals` in the following code are `np.float64` but not `np.float32` as you expect.

To fix it, you can do something like that:

```
                normal = np.cross(face_vertices[0]-face_vertices[1], face_vertices[2] - face_vertices[1])
                normal /= np.linalg.norm(normal)
                flt_normal = np.array(normal, dtype=np.float32)
 
                self.vertices = np.append(self.vertices, face_vertices)
                for i in range(3): self.normals = np.append(self.normals, flt_normal)
```

With regards to shaders, you indeed need to use `mat3x3` for `vec3` normal transformation. Additionally, `transpose` is equal to `inverse` for rotation matrices, so `inverse(transpose(Rot)) = Rot`. So it looks redundant, you can rewrite it as:

```
    fNormal.xyz = mat3x3(MVMatrix) * normalize(vNormal.xyz);
```

And don't forget to check normal direction in the fragment shader. It looks like it should be:

```
float diff = max(dot(-vec3(fNormal), diffLightDir), 0.0);
```

Comment: It works great, but why does float64 mess things up so severely?

Comment: float64 takes 8 bytes, float32 - 4 bytes. When you write a normal as float64, it takes 24 bytes. When you get it in the shader it reads the first 12 bytes from it, because interpret it as vec3 of float32

Answer (score 1):

`vNormal` is a vector with 3 components. You have to transform the normal vector with the normal matrix. The normal matrix is the inverse transpose of the upper left 3x3 components of the model view matrix (no translation):

```c
vec3 normal = normalize(inverse(transpose(mat3(MVMatrix))) * vNormal.xyz);
```

This is the same as:

```c
fNormal = normalize(inverse(transpose(MVMatrix)) * vec4(vNormal.xyz, 0.0));
```

If an attribute is not specified or only partially specified, the x, y, and z components default to 0.0, but the w component defaults to 1.0. So what you're actually doing is
`fNormal = normalize(inverse(transpose(MVMatrix)) * vec4(vNormal.xyz, 1.0));`, and that's wrong because you're applying the translation of the model view matrix to the normal vector

Also `fNormal` must be normalized in the fragment shader, because by the interpolation the length does not remain 1.0.

Comment: I tried doing this, even directly copy-pasting your code, and the same problems appear, but the inconsistency happens in different places

Comment: The normalization in the frag shader smoothed out some of the inconsistency

Comment: @User12692182 So there is another problem that I can't spot yet. Are you sure that all normal vectors point in the same logical direction?

Comment: @User12692182 For debug reasons try: `vec3 normal = vec3(fNormal) * sign(fNormal.z);` (fragment shader). Then use `normal` instead of `fNormal`.

Comment: I tried turning fNormal into a vec3 before normalizing it, and I implemented your debug. The camera angle now has almost no effect, but the lighting is still inconsistent between adjacent vertices

Comment: I checked the first normal in the normal list against the first triangle, and it was good. I also checked that the same normal was repeated 3 times in the normal list

Comment: @User12692182 Your normals are calculated from the faces with the cross product. So if the winding order of a face is wrong, the normals will also point in the wrong direction. Have you tried `vec3 normal = vec3(fNormal) * sign(fNormal.z);`?

Comment: I did try that, albeit normalizing it too. I removed the normalization and the camera angle matters once again

Comment: My entire source code is here: https://pastebin.com/ANjPdP3D. The obj file in stl form is here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5619934, but any geometry should pose problematic. It's a little messy, but I'm just trying to get something working before I make a real program